# Create column that makes summation to a scalar

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
          valor
BB        435.116
CEL      -1439.250
DI        132.300
AC        560.500
```

and the following scalar:

```
x=2000
```

what is the best way of generating a new column that makes the summation to valor in each row?

The desired output would look something like this:

```
          valor      summ
BB        435.116    2435.116
CEL      -1439.250   995.866
DI        132.300   1128.166
AC        560.500   1688.666
```

where to the initial scalar adds the value in the corresponding row

Is there a simple way to perform this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using `cumsum`

```
df['summ']=df.cumsum()+2000
df
Out[208]: 
        valor      summ
BB    435.116  2435.116
CEL -1439.250   995.866
DI    132.300  1128.166
AC    560.500  1688.666
```